# jquery get radio value on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am using: http://blogs.digitss.com/javascript/jquery-javascript/jquery-fancy-custom-radio-and-checkbox/

simple code:

```
<input type="radio" id="a1" class="b1" name="shipping" checked value="single">
<input type="radio" id="a1" class="b1" name="shipping" value="married">
<input type="radio" id="a1" class="b1" name="shipping" value="widowed">
```

simple head:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".radio").dgStyle();
    $(".checkbox").dgStyle();

});
```

if i add to $(document).ready , after ($".checkbox").dgStyle();  The following:

```
alert($('input:radio[name=shipping]:checked').val());
```

it works fine!

but - if i do something like that, it is not working:

```
$(function() {

    $("input:radio[name=shipping]:checked").change(function() {
        alert("123");
    });

});
```

i tried to remove :checked, still not working.

- maybe you know different jquery custom buttons in that same colors, which can does it..?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/vsk3V/

Comment: do you want it like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ds4Qg/2/

Comment: i got into conclusion that because i use a custom styled radio, i can't call change() function. if i remove the custom radio, it works fine. do you know a way to pass through it? or perhaps another way to make custom buttons which i can actually see their change. thanks!

Comment: OMG! its a div! and not really a checkbox or radio button..

Comment: really? weird... you know what i can do about it anyway?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I got this:

```
$(".radio").click(function() {        
    alert('ID : ' + $(this).find('input:radio').prop('id'));
    alert('Value : ' + $(this).find('input:radio').prop('value'));
});
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/EP92E/)

Answer (score 3):

You must remove the `:checked` on the selector

```
$(function() {
    $("input:radio[name=shipping]").change(function() {
        alert('123');
    });
});
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ds4Qg/2/)***

**NOTE**: please make sure you don't use same ID's on your elements its really a bad practice or else you will face a lot of issues